# How to use xpath to count by text content

Tags: sql-server, xml, select

Counting the number of "Hello" occurrences. "Hello" is Case Sensitive.

```
<test>
    <item>
        <id>hello</id>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>Hello</id>
    </item>
</test>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok **I got the answer** by myself.
The query must be like this:

```
SELECT 

ISNULL(COL_XML.value('count(/test/item/id[text()="Hello"])','INT'), 0)

FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Be aware that the text you are looking for in this case "Hello" is **Case Sensitive**.

Comment: Good!. Now accept your answer; Yes you can accept your own answer. This helps others with the same problem by flagging your question as having an accepted answer.

Comment: According to stackoverflow I can accept my answer until tomorrow. I will do it. Thank you community.